# Show collection view by using scss file in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I' like to show the question model information as collection view like picture1. However, I have no idea how to do it. 
My present view is like picture2. I want to show each question body as collection view, not table view.
The following is present scss and view file.
Could you tell me how to achieve the collection view on rails?

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

.questions {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  color: #000000;
  // width:300px;
  // height:100px;
  // background:gray;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 4gba(0,0,0,0.2);

  div {
    display:inline;
  }

  li {
    padding: 50px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  }
}
.content {
  display: block;
}

#app/views/questions/show.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <h3>Popular</h3>
    <div class = "questions">
      <%= render @questions %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Picture1
[image: picture1]

Picture2
[image: picture2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to read bootstrap's doc (http://getbootstrap.com/css/). You can use for instance Boostrap's thumbnails and modify the styles. By adding col-md-4 like I did, you'll have 3 questions per row.

```
<div class="row">
   <h3>Popular</h3>
   <%= render @questions %>
</div>
```

In _question.html.erb:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <%= link_to question, class: "thumbnail" do %>
       <%= image_tag question.image %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
```